# Can unused function-arguments become optimized away?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to ensure an object - wrapped by a `shared_ptr` - is alive as long as a function is executed by passing it as value. However inside the function the object is not used at all, so I just want to use it for 'pinning':

```
void doSomething(std::shared_ptr<Foo>) {
    // Perform some operations unrelated to the passed shared_ptr.
}

int main() {
    auto myFoo{std::make_shared<Foo>()};
    doSomething(std::move(myFoo)); // Is 'myFoo' kept alive until doSomething returns?
    return 0;
}
```

I did check the behavior on different optimization-levels (GCC) and it seems that it works as intended, however I don't know whether the compiler still may optimize it away in certain scenarios.

Comment: A compiler is always allowed to reorder all actions as long the code is working "as if" written. So your code has a good chance to have only "return 0" from main here!

Comment: You're right - it's a very contrieved example. Let's assume there's some side-effect in terms of `doSomething()` as well as the destructor of `Foo` is doing some `cout`. My expectation then would be the printing of the function shows up before the one coming from the destructor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to worry - the lifetime of the function argument at the *call site* is guaranteed to survive the function call. (This is why things like `foo(s.c_str())` for a `std::string s` work.)

A compiler is not allowed to break that rule, subject to *as if* rule flexibility.

Comment: Alright - and this does also apply if the function parameter is not used in the function itself at all, right?

Comment: @Phlar: Absolutely. Yes the compiler is allowed to make optimisations, but it must not change the program behaviour.

Comment: There's one interesting *as if* rule exception, which is regarding constructor elision.  There, a compiler can change program behavior if the constructor has side-effects, since the side-effects won't happen if the constructor is elided.

Comment: @Eljay: And also some [allocations in new expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Allocation) since C++14.

Answer (score 1):

This very much depends on what the body of `doSomething` and `Foo` will actually look like. For instance, consider the following example:

```
struct X 
{
    ~X() { std::cout << "2"; };
};

void f(std::shared_ptr<X>) { std::cout << "1"; }

int main()
{
    auto p = std::make_shared<X>();
    f(std::move(p));
}
```

This program has the very same observable effect as:

```
int main()
{
  std::cout << "12";
}
```

and the order `"12"` is guaranteed. So, in the generated assembly, there may be no shared pointer used. However, most compilers will likely not perform such aggressive optimizations since there are dynamic memory allocations and virtual function calls involved internally, which is not that easy to optimize away.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler could optimise away the copying of an object into a function argument if the function is being inlined and if the copying has no side effects.

Copying a `shared_ptr` increments its reference count so it does have side effects so the compiler can't optimise it away (unless the compiler can prove to itself that not modifying the reference count has no effect on the program).

Comment: But, what if the reference count is not involved in the observable effect of the program? That's kind of a different topic, but `int main() { auto ptr = std::make_shared<int>(); }` has the same effect as empty `main` under as-if rule.

Comment: @DanielLangr possibly, I'm not sure if optimisers are able to remove atomic increment/decrements?

Comment: `std::atomic` isn't observable, but `volatile` is from [as_if rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if).